# Как исправить код на c++11 при переходе на более раннюю версию компилятора qcc

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть (рыба) паттерн кода который работоспособен уже на версии gcc 4.8.1  и далее на свежих версиях (Астра Linux 1.6).  Основная идея в том что структура AF содержит статические массивы, и набор констант которые затем используются для инициализации объектов класса flt через механизм параметризации.

В коде реализовано довольно такого рода паттернов и  как обычно, внезапно, потребовалось чтобы код
работал на версии gcc 4.7.2 (Астра Linux 1.5). Но он не собирается.

Проверял возможность сборки различными версиями gcc на сайте https://wandbox.org/.

Какие есть предложения по минимальному изменению кода с целью сохранения работоспособности при понижении  версии компилятора до gcc 4.7.2. Желательно сохранить параметризацию! Заранее благодарен

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct AF
{
const  int a_L{3};
static constexpr double m_H[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};
};
//////////////////////////////////////

template <typename F>
class flt{
   
    public:
          flt()
             {
             double mn[3];
             mn[0]=F::m_H[0]; 
             mn[1]=F::m_H[1];
             mn[0]*=1;
             mn[1]*=1;
            }
    
    
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main()
{
    flt<AF> f1; 
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
    
}
```

Comment: [Компилируется с gcc 4.7.2](https://godbolt.org/z/syb7Qy)

Comment: Компилируется а потом следует ошибка линкера  
"undefined reference to `AF::m_H'"

Comment: Укажите определение вне класса

Comment: Спасибо за на_водку, принято и работает!

Comment: перенёс в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указать определение `m_H` вне класса.

[Ответ с пояснениями, почему так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846608).

[Ещё один на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619534/394322)