# Почему static переменные определяются вне класса

Tags: c++, классы, static

Я заранее извиняюсь за свой вопрос, т. к. он очень похож на [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619530/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-static-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5), но я бы его не задавал, если бы мне было хоть что-то понятно. Я действительно не могу понять, почему статические поля определяются вне класса. Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах, настолько я глупый :)

Comment: Наверное вы имеете в виду не класс, а экземпляр класса. Идея в том, что все статические части класса должны быть одинаковы во всех его экземплярах

Comment: Потому что так написано в стандарте языка :) Обычно объявление класса помещают в заголовочный файл, который включается в несколько cpp-файлов. Таким образом, если определить статическую переменную внутри класса, то она окажется включённой в несколько cpp-файлов. А значит нужно как-то решить проблему определения одной и той же сущности в несколькольких единицах трансляции, а также проблему с [порядком инициализации статических переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/912645).

Comment: В качестве решения данных проблем выбран путь наименьшего сопротивления: пусть программист сам выберет конкретный cpp-файл в котором будет объявлен/инициализирован статический член класса. Только не спрашивайте, почему всё-таки принято _именно такое_ решение, а не какое-нибудь другое. Стандарт пишут люди, никто не обещает, что принимаемые ими решения окажутся наиболее оптимальными по тем или иныим критериям. Ну и плюс тяжелейшее бремя обратной совместимости. То что казалось здравой идеей лет 30 назад, может вызывать недоумение сегодня.

Comment: Ну, собственно, стандарты посвежее этого уже не требуют, допуская объявление `inline static`...

Comment: @wololo, спасибо огромное, до меня наконец то дошло:)

Comment: @Harry, кстати да, но хотелось бы уточнить, inline говорит компилятору о том, что нам неважно где определяется переменная и это значит, что она для каждого файла будет своя или она все таки будет  одна?

Comment: Одна на все файлы, конечно.